# Can't generate a public key for Android in app billing V3 due to multiple APK versions

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I want to use the new in App billing, but I am using the multiple APK feature in the play console, so the new console which is where you go to get that key doesn't yet support my apps.

[image: console view]

So how do I get such a key? Has anyone figured this out? Question was also asked here:

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/R8DKwZDsz5m

Comment: Does using the old design work?

Comment: switch back to the old design?

Comment: Guys, the old play design does not support the new V3 Google billing library. Basically Google rushed to market with partial support for it's developers. And with no customer support contact, I'm relying on good people to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deactivate the APK on the old console, then switch to the new, copy the license key, and then switch again to old design and activate the APK again.

Answer (score 0):

It sucks doesn't it? There is currently no way to get the key if you are using multiple APKs. I was told it should be fixed 'soon' on G+, not much to do but wait...

v3 feels unfinished and we still don't know how well it works in practice. I would evaluate it in a new (test) app for now, but hold off upgrading existing apps for a while. Although the inventory/get local price is nice to have and it does work synchronously (you don't have to wait for a GCM notification for purchase success, and those tend to get lost), which *should* bring up your success rate a bit.

BTW, the key is automatically generated, so it's there, you just cannot get to it. Another thing to watch out for is that v2 requires Android 2.2, so if you want to support 2.1 (or 1.6, but that's less relevant) you have to keep one APK version with v2.